# Does Apple have a way to copy one view's appearance (i.e. what you physically see on screen) into an image buffer?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimage, calayer

We have a UIView that, when tapped, we want a 'copy' of what appears on screen to simultaneously move up, grow and fade out as a visual cue that the user tapped on that particular item.  Think of it as similar to 'liking' something on a site to give it a little visual flair.  Does Apple have any built-in way to retrieve a copy of what visually appears on the screen into an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s called a snapshot view.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotview

Comment: By the way taking a snapshot view is a lot faster than the layer based `render(in)`.

Comment: No need. Like I said, I can respect your position.

Answer (score 2):

**Simplified Update**

Here's a version of the `animateUserReaction` extension that uses `UIView`'s built-in `snapshotView` function, eliminating the need for the `makeImageSnapshot` helper function.

```
func animateUserReaction() {

    guard let containerView = superview,
          let snapshotView  = snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates:true)
    else {
        return
    }

    // Make sure to match the frame to the current frame
    snapshotView.frame = frame

    containerView.addSubview(snapshotView)

    UIView.animate(
        withDuration : 0.5,
        delay        : 0,
        options      : [.beginFromCurrentState, .curveEaseOut],
        animations: {
            snapshotView.transform       = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
            snapshotView.frame.origin.y -= snapshotView.frame.size.height * 1.5
            snapshotView.alpha           = 0
        },
        completion: { _ in
            snapshotView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    )
}
```

---

**Original answer...**

Got it! It's from a coworker who doesn't have a StackOverflow account (??!!!) but here it is!  Perfect!  Thanks, Jon! Now get an account!!!

Make a copy of a UIView and store in a UIImage

```
extension UIView {

    func makeImageSnapshot() -> UIImage? {
        // NOTE: 0.0 scale is to respect retina (prevents pixelation)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        defer {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
        }

        layer.render(in: context)

        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

Animate that copy...

```
extension UIView {

    func animateSnapshotOfSelf() {

        guard let containerView = superview,
              let snapshot      = makeImageSnapshot()
        else {
            return
        }

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        imageView.image = snapshot
        containerView.addSubview(imageView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, delay: 0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState, .curveEaseOut], animations: {
            imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
            imageView.frame.origin.y += -100
            imageView.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { _ in
            imageView.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: (I don't much about this, so I don't know whether or not this would be a good idea) Could you achieve the same thing by animating the original view in the same manner? YOu just have to disable it to prevent interaction during the animation

Comment: The original view has to stay where it is.